# How to save data from tableview to database?

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I'm failing to save the data edit in table view cell. when i edit those data then i press enter but the data isn't save in my database. i don't know how to do that.
that's my code

```
public String getValueAt(TableView<Note> table, int column, int row){
        return table.getColumns().get(column).getCellObservableValue(row).getValue().toString();
    }


    @FXML
    void updateData(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String sql = "UPDATE NOTES set note = '"+getValueAt(tableView,2,0)+"', coef = '"+getValueAt(tableView,3,0)+"', total = '"+getValueAt(tableView,4,0)+"', appreciation = '"+getValueAt(tableView,5,0)+"' where noteMatri = '"+getValueAt(tableView,0,0)+"';" ;

        Connection con = FirstConnection.Connect();
        Statement pst = con.createStatement();

        String e =  getValueAt(tableView,0,0);
        System.out.println(e);
        String f = getValueAt(tableView,1,0);
        System.out.println(f);
        String a = getValueAt(tableView,2,0);
        System.out.println(a);
        String b = getValueAt(tableView,3,0);
        System.out.println(b);
        String c = getValueAt(tableView,4,0);
        System.out.println(c);
        String d = getValueAt(tableView,5,0);
        System.out.println(d);

        int i = pst.executeUpdate(sql);
        if(i == 1){
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Mise � jour effectu�e");
            alert.setHeaderText("Enregistrement d'�l�ments");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

    }
```

The row is affected successfully, but when I look on my database the data wasn't updated. please help me to retrieve what i do wrong.

Comment: How do you know "The row is affected successfully"? Do you commit?

Comment: the alert box is showing succesfully updated

Comment: How many rows are said to have been updated?

Comment: one row as been updated

Comment: Looks promising. Do you commit?

Comment: no i haven't. at this step i don't know what i have to do

Comment: I mean commit the update. See the answer you've got below.

Comment: what is the way to commit it ?

Comment: [mcve] please .. btw, accessing table values as you do is extremely unusual (typically only for advanced useage), what's wrong with grabbing the row item (from the table's items collection) and update the backend with it's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html

> Once your cell is in an editing state, the next thing you are most probably interested in is how to commit or cancel the editing that is taking place. This is your responsibility as the cell factory provider. Your cell implementation will know when the editing is over, based on the user input (e.g. when the user presses the Enter or ESC keys on their keyboard). When this happens, it is your responsibility to call Cell.commitEdit(Object) or Cell.cancelEdit(), as appropriate.

As @jarlh asked, "Do you commit?"

Comment: basically yeah, but in most cases the cell implementations (f.i. TextFieldTableCell) coming with javafx are good enough, so client code is just _client_ not cell implementor :)